# Column named cannot be found. Parameter name

Tags: vb.net

i'm using VB.NET, and i'm getting error "Column named NoMutasi cannot be found. Parameter name"

this my code

```
With dt
        .Columns.Add("NoMutasi")
        .Columns.Add("nama")
        .Columns.Add("alamat")
        .Columns.Add("noRute")
        .Columns.Add("nmRute")
        .Columns.Add("nmMedia")
        .Columns.Add("noEdisi")
        .Columns.Add("colyFieldVariable")
        .Columns.Add("jatahAgen")
    End With

    For Each rd As DataGridViewRow In Me.DataGridView1.Rows
        dt.Rows.Add(rd.Cells("NoMutasi").Value, rd.Cells("NmAgen").Value, rd.Cells("AlamatAgen").Value, rd.Cells("NoRute").Value, rd.Cells("NmRute").Value, rd.Cells("NmMedia").Value, rd.Cells("NoEdisi").Value, rd.Cells("colyFieldVariable").Value, rd.Cells("JatahAgen").Value)
    Next
```

and here the other one's

```
                noMutasi = dr.Item("NoMutasi")
                nama = dr.Item("NmAgen")
                colyFieldVariable = batas Mod 100
                alamat = dr.Item("alamatAgen")
                noRute = dr.Item("NoRute")
                nmRute = dr.Item("NmRute")
                nmMedia = dr.Item("NmMedia")
                noEdisi = dr.Item("NoEdisi")
                jatahAgen = dr.Item("JatahAgen")
                Dim row As String() = New String() {noMutasi, nama, alamat, noRute, nmRute, nmMedia, noEdisi, colyFieldVariable, jatahAgen}
                DataGridView1.Rows.Add(row)
```

Comment: Do you have a column named _noMutasi_ in your DataGridView? You are reading FIRST from the grid THEN add to the datatable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to access the data by column name, but you did not add column names. See example here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.columns(v=vs.110).aspx

```
' Add columns (ie headers)
DataGridView1.Columns(0).Name = "NoMutasi"
DataGridView1.Columns(1).Name = "nama"
DataGridView1.Columns(2).Name = "alamat"
'etc...

' Then add the data row
Dim row As String() = New String() {noMutasi, nama, alamat}
DataGridView1.Rows.Add(row)
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10362263)

Comment: Edited. Thanks for the feedback.